# Trim the last character at the end of string

Tags: json, loops, vbscript, asp-classic

I have a loop that is creating a string until the end of the file. Depending on how many products I have at the time. I need to trim the last comma at the end.

I get:

```
{ sku: '6200', display_name:'Product 1', unit_price: 497.37, qty: 1 },  
{ sku: '2344', display_name:'Product 2', unit_price: 824.21, qty: 1 },
```

I need:

```
{ sku: '6200', display_name:'Product 1', unit_price: 497.37, qty: 1 },  
{ sku: '2344', display_name:'Product 2', unit_price: 824.21, qty: 1 }
```

Loop:

```
<%
set rsheadercart = db.execute(sqlheadercart)
    if not rsheadercart.eof then 
        do until rsheadercart.eof 




            items = items & " { sku: '" & rsheadercart("ten_digit_part_number") & "',"
            items = items & " display_name:'" & rsheadercart("part_name") & "',"
            items = items & " unit_price: " & rsheadercart("price") & ","
            items = items & " qty: " & rsheadercart("quantity") & " }, "


        rsheadercart.movenext
        loop 
        %>
<%
end if 
%>
```

Comment: This is not VBA.

Comment: Maybe count how many times you loop and store it in a variable, after the loop remove the last character when its bigger than 1.

Comment: This looks like Classic ASP.  It can't be both Classic ASP and ASP.net

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move your comma to the beginning of the loop and put it in a conditional statement so that it isn't executed at the first iteration

```
do until rsheadercart.eof 

    If items <> "" then 
       items = items & ","
    End If     

    items = items & " { sku: '" & rsheadercart("ten_digit_part_number") & "',"
    items = items & " display_name:'" & rsheadercart("part_name") & "',"
    items = items & " unit_price: " & rsheadercart("price") & ","
    items = items & " qty: " & rsheadercart("quantity") & " } "

rsheadercart.movenext
loop
```

Comment: That got rid of the comma at the end but now there is a comma at the very beginning

Comment: Maybe try a different condition, like `If items <> "" then`.  If items already has a value at the beginning of the loop then use that value instead of empty quotes.

Comment: `I've edited the answer so that it shows the correct conditional statement.

Comment: No need for all that clutter, just deal with the last comma after the loop has finished - `items = Left(items, Len(items) - 1)`.

Comment: You can also add the if-statement after the `rsheadercart.movenext` and check against `if NOT rsheadercart.eof` if it feels more natural to add the comma at the end of each loop rather than at the start. While Lankymart's solution probably is a bit cleaner for this case, there are other use cases where having the logic inside the loop is a good technique to consider.

Answer (score 6):

Have found the simplest way over the years is to let the loop generate the extra character than just trim it after the execution of the loop using `Left()`.

After your loop add;

```
items = Left(items, Len(items) - 1)
```

This way avoids having to add a load of logic into the loop to handle the edge cases unnecessarily.

Comment: Yes! This is much cleaner than doing an `If`clause every iteration of the loop.  More efficient, and easier to read.

Answer (score 1):

In cases like that I often use the [Join](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/internet-explorer/ie-developer/scripting-articles/yscc53h0(v=vs.84)) method

```
dim itemList 
set itemList = CreateObject("System.Collections.ArrayList")
do until rsheadercart.eof 
    dim item       
    item = " { sku: '" & rsheadercart("ten_digit_part_number") & "',"
    item = item & " display_name:'" & rsheadercart("part_name") & "',"
    item = item & " unit_price: " & rsheadercart("price") & ","
    item = item & " qty: " & rsheadercart("quantity") & " } "
    itemList.Add item
    rsheadercart.movenext
loop 
items = Join(itemList.ToArray,",")
```

If you don't want to use an Arraylist, you can do the same with an plain array, but you would have to redim it each iteration.

Comment: Since VBScript hoists variables, you need to clear the contents of `item` in each iteration, `Dim item` inside the loop does not do that for you. That line only runs once at run time.

Comment: @Kul-Tigin well spotted. Fixed it.